# MySQL - Deleting all but newest rows with composite key

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns like this:

`id   timestamp   content`

where ID is a string, and timestamp is `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

`id` and `timestamp` together make a composite key, so you can select the newest colum with something like:

`select * from table where id = 'text-here' order by timestamp desc limit 1`

I now have a problem where I want to delete all but the newest entry for each `id`, but I have no idea how to do this. If it had an auto-incrementing primary key I could use a sub-query to select the ones to keep and use `NOT IN`, as is demonstrated on numerous questions here, but I don't know how to do this with a composite key.

Comment: `WHERE timestamp <> MAX(timestamp)`

Comment: @hjpotter92 - I don't see how that would account for the varying `id`'s - wouldn't that delete all but one row, regardless of `id`?

Comment: The above condition is to be `AND`ed w/ your `id` restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible without a subquery too:

```
DELETE t
FROM t
JOIN t AS t2 ON t.timestamp < t2.timestamp AND t.id = t2.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ff88/1

Comment: Thats good then. Just for info, the version by @GiorgosBetsos may be faster in some cases, depending on number of different IDs and timestamps.

Answer (score 3):

The following query:

```
DELETE mytable
FROM mytable
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(`timestamp`) AS `timestamp`
            FROM mytable
            GROUP BY id) AS t
ON mytable.id = t.id AND mytable.`timestamp` < t.`timestamp`
```

deletes all but the newest record per `id` from `mytable`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/feddc/1)

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. However, I'm selecting jkavalik's answer because it doesn't rely on a subquery, which is more portable.